# How to use Jenkins credential in downstream promoted build?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to trigger a job (we'll call it `downstream`) from a parent job promotion (we'll call it `parent`) using the [promoted builds](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds/) plugin. But the `downstream` job fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID '${credentialssh}'
```

The `parent` job has a promotion which is passing parameter `credentialssh=mycred` in the *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* action. This triggers the `downstream` job.

The `downstream` job is parameterized with a parameter type of *Credential Parameter* set to *name* `credentialssh`. The credential type is SSH username with private key. The build environment is set to *Use secret text(s) or file(s)*. there is a binding for *SSH User Private Key* and the parameter expansion is set to `${credentialssh}`.

I have a *SSH Username with private key* global credential with ID `mycred`.

It fails when running the promotion from `parent`. But when I run the `downstream` job manually (selecting the `mycred` credential) it works.

Versions:

- Jenkins 2.204.2
- Credentials Binding 1.20
- Credentials Plugin 2.3.1
- promoted builds plugin 3.5

Potentially related Jenkins Jira issues (which I am not quite certain how to handle based on comments):

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23977
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58967

How can I get this working from the promoted builds plugin?